# Grouping gps-points by location and time using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, gps

I tracked my holiday-routes with some friends for many years. We tracked 3 cars each year, every car with another GPS-Tracker. The GPS-Tracker locate the position every 10 minutes. I'm using QGIS 3.2 and have at least about 1 million GPS-Points.

Now i want to route every year as a line, not the single cars.
I have Attributes about:
1. Identifier per way
2. timestamp
3. lat
4. lon

Would it work with a time-distance-matrix to group the points by location and attributes?

Comment: Have you tried to filter your timestamp with an expression like this: "timestamp" > '2015-01-01'?

Comment: Yes, i tried at least the points to line. Grouped by an attribute year and sorted by timestamp. The problem here is that some points, which are „later“ by timestamp, are „behind“ the gps-track before from the other car (e.g. Car A takes a lunchbreak, Car B is still on road).